# RTD reads differently with different monitors

Tags: noise, rtd

I have an RTD that I am reading with a [Jenco 77A  4-20mA converter](https://jencoi.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/77.pdf) and a reliable 4-20mA supply/display. When I turn on a nearby AC electric motor, the indicated temperature jumps 50°C (which is clearly not actually happening).

However, when I disconnect the RTD wires from the converter and read them with a [mulitmeter](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/electrical-testing/digital-multimeters/fluke-115#), I see a steady resistance reading.

I have confirmed that the converter works with other RTDs, and that the same problem occurs with the same RTD on identical converters.

Why would the resistance measurement be so wrong on one measurement system but accurate on another? Are there any commons means to fix this problem?

Comment: Manual says:"Thermocouple  input  is  not  electrically  isolated  from  current  output,  so  installation  precaution  must  be  observed  to  avoid   ground   loops.   Insulated   (un-grounded)   thermocouple   probes   are   strongly   recommended." Seems like you have a noise problem, which suggests using the recommended connection method to solve it.

Comment: OP has an RTD (resistance) which is almost always isolated from ground. Thermocouples come in both forms with the isolated type inferior to vastly inferior as a sensor but it makes the circuitry much cheaper and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

They're really low-end non-isolated transmitters (not so bad for RTD but that's a really bad thing for serious industrial thermocouple applications).

Check that there is no circuit to ground with a multimeter. If there is none (I suspect that's not the problem) it may be responding to EMI from a VFD driving the AC motor. It's not hard for an amateur to design a circuit that rectifies the interference and produces a DC offset. Nonlinearity in the front end circuitry.

You can try to add capacitors across the inputs, shielding the sensor wires, shielding and separating the motor wires from sensor wires, etc. but I believe you'd be better off with a better designed product if you actually care about the reading. 50°C is a seriously bad offset (represents about 20mV at the front end for PT100 which is nothing short of horrible, it would be of the order of 500°C on a K thermocouple).

Comment: Thanks, Spehro. Can you recommend a spec I should look for on a better RTD monitor to indicate noise resistance?

Comment: I think one relevant spec would be IEC 61326. Eg. [this](https://i.imgur.com/M5Oitmh.png).

Comment: The self-recovery comment more applies to a microcontroller-based signal conditioner which is allowed to be disrupted by extreme EMI, but must recover on its own.